# Smarty : explode

Tags: smarty

> branch_name = ["computer science","Science And Information Technology","Information science"]

these array values are user input values.
I want to display this branch name but I can only display 15 letters
then it will output like:

```
computer scienc
science and inf
information sci
```

but i want

```
computer
science and
information
```

```
{assign var="bn" value=""|explode:"Computer Information Science "} 
{$bn|@count}
```

but its giving wrong output as 1

Comment: `{assign var="bn" value=""|explode:"Computer Science"}` So you want to explode from nothing `""` in `Computer Science`? I think you need the missing space in `value=" "` `{assign var="bn" value=" "|explode:"Computer Science"}`

Comment: {assign var="bn" value=""|explode:"Computer Science And Information"} then also the output is 1

Comment: Don't you just need the [truncate](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl) function???

Comment: 1. Click the link. 2. try out `{"Science And Information Technology"|truncate:15:"..."}` outputs `Science And Inf...` 3. Gratzz + link http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl

Comment: first i want to know how many words are there

Comment: You do this `branch_name|count` return 3 then `value=","|explode:"computer science","Science And Information Technology","Information science"` return 3 strings now you truncate them..